# Dispatch to run code on background without UI waiting?

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch

I'm making an application in which I do download some stuffs once I connect. I fulfill my `CoreData` without downloading my pictures. Now, once I connected, I push my segue and get a main screen.

Now what I want is to be able to swap my screens and download the pictures at the same time.

I do download from a `Singleton` class this way:

```
        let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        let tmp = DownloadManagerSingleton.sharedInstance
        tmp.startDownloads()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
        })
    })
```

I can't find any way to download on background mode without the UI being locked until the downloads are finished. Am I doing this wrong or is there another way to fulfill my goal ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no reason  why what you wrote above shouldn't work. Without seeing what startDownloads actually does, and what your UI code is doing, I don't see what would be causing your UI to get stuck.

Comment: Also, there's really no need to use dispatch_async, if your download class is using the Foundation-provided NSURLSession, etc. Those classes all support background downloading without any special effort on the developer's part.

Comment: My problem was coming from a loop within startDownloads, I deleted it then rewrote it and it started working fine. I chose to use the dispatch because of this loop since I knew downloading through NSURL would handle the async downloads but the loop would have blocked up my code !